# ubuntu python socket error [errno 111]

Tags: python, sockets

I used python to analyze the online ad system. I try to connect to the server but failed, the template of the code I run in terminal is: `python client.py username portnumber`,

here is the code on server side:

```
import sys
import time
import socket
TIMEOUT = 30

class Firefly:
def __init__(self, port):
    self._port = port
def _get_the_dataz(self, s):
    ret = ""
    s.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
    while True:
        data = s.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        ret = ret + data;
    return ret

def _send_command(self, command, retries=3):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #s.connect(('127.0.0.1', self._port))
        s.connect(('localhost', self._port))
        s.send(command)
        ret = self._get_the_dataz(s)
        s.close()
        return ret
    except socket.error as ex:
        print "Firefly timeout, %d retries left" % retries
        print str(ex)

        if retries == 0:
            print "Can't reach firefly on port %d!" % self._port
            raise
        retries -= 1
        time.sleep([30, 10, 2][retries])
        return self._send_command(command, retries)

def get_visual_elements(self, url):
    return self._send_command('GOTO %s' % url)
```

It always returns like this:

> ```
> [errno 111] connection refused
> cannot reach server on port 80
> traceback(most recent call last):
> file "server.py", line 27, in _send_command
>   s.connect(('localhost', self._port))
> file "server.py", line 224, in meth
>   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
> ```

then I try **"telnet 127.0.0.1 80"**,
It returns:

> unable to connect to the remote host, connection refused.

What should I do?

Comment: Do a netstat and find out if there is any process listening to port 80, in case it is not, run the server/process.

Comment: I tried, there is no process listening to port 80, but i still cannot connect to the server, actually, no matter what port number i used, i failed to connect to the server.

Comment: How can you connect if there is no process listening?!

Comment: The code you show is a client trying to connect on the port. Its not a server listening on the port. Are you expecting that code to accept connections on port 80? If so, look up server examples that use `listen()` and `accept()` calls.

Comment: My professor asked me to use the tool he provided, i just followed the guidance, and found the error. i really new to python and ubuntu, here is the link:https://github.com/ACAHNN/adscape